# Sampler3D in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-3.0

I have just include OpenGL ES 3.0 in my iOS app and it is working fine.

I have a working shader below:

```
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D texSampler;
uniform float fExposure;

in vec2 fTexCoord;
in vec3 fColor;

out vec4 fragmentColor;

void main()
{
  fragmentColor = texture(texSampler, fTexCoord) * vec4(fColor, 1.0) * fExposure;
}
```

Now, I want to use a `sampler3D` so I have:

```
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler3D texSampler;
uniform float fExposure;

in vec3 fTexCoord;
in vec3 fColor;

out vec4 fragmentColor;

void main()
{
  fragmentColor = texture(texSampler, fTexCoord) * vec4(fColor, 1.0) * fExposure;
}
```

and it doesn't compile. Also, I changed the `vec2 texCoord` to `vec3 texCoord` in the vertex shader.

Actually, `sampler3D` is not recognized, but as far as i know it exists in OpenGL ES 3.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: "it doesn't compile"...What did the shader compilation log say?

Comment: I get the compile status glGetProgramiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result); result is 0 and the shader infolog is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to `float`, `sampler3D` does not have a default precision. Add this at the start of your fragment shader, where you also specify the default `float` precision:

```
precision mediump sampler3D;
```

Of course you can use `lowp` instead if that gives you sufficient precision.

The only sampler types that have a default precision in ES 3.0/3.1 are `sampler2D` and `samplerCube` (both default to `lowp`). For all others, the precision has to be specified either as a default precision, or as part of the variable declaration.